# Cocos2d - Creating a scene

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

What is the use of the following code when creating a scene:

```
 +(CCScene *)scene {

    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    Game *layer = [Game node];
    [scene addChild:layer];
    return scene;   
}
```

Here we initialize a generic CCScene object, and add a layer of class "Game" (which is a CCScene class containing our +scene method) to it.

Would the following give the same result?

```
   +(CCScene *)scene {

        Game *scene = [Game node];
        return scene;   
    }
```

Comment: is `Game` a `CCScene` or `CCLayer`?

Comment: It's a CCScene. Forgot to mention it :)

Comment: than the new method should be fine. first method should be used if `Game` is `CCLayer`

Comment: In that case, if you needed this layer in a transition, you could call [Game scene] to create a scene + the Game layer?

Comment: Yes. The whole +(id) scene method is bollocks because neither do you need layers nor does the scene class serve any other purpose than being required by director. In fact you can create a CCNode and cast it to CCScene when calling replaceScene.